# Why won't this execute command work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a datapack and in it you cannot sleep unless you are `y 100` or above, but my command doesn't work. Can anyone explain why P.S: `playerheight` is a scoreboard that updates according to the Y coordinate.

```
execute at @e[tag=avian,scores={slep=1..}] if score @p[tag=avian]  
playerheight < 100 run run setblock ~ ~ ~ air destroy
```

Comment: Maybe you have misspelled sleep/slept as slep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### There are multiple things, that might be wrong:

Your sleeping scoreboard is misspelled `slep`, which might cause issues, unless you've have the same misspelling everywhere.

You're using `<`. This compares the score of two players/entities in two scoreboards. Your code would compare the score of `@p[tag=avian]` in `playerheight` with the score of `100` in `run`. What you want is `matches`: `if score @p[tag=avian] playerheight matches ..100`.

#### Also note two things:

You can check multiple scores at once:
`execute at @e[tag=avian,scores={sleep=1..,playerheight=..100}]`

And for the height of a player you don't even need a scoreboard:
`execute at @e[tag=avian,scores={sleep=1..},y=100,dy=-200]`

Comment: slep is deliberate, and i plan to use playerheight loads so i thought a scoreboard would be good. thanks!